# GnuCash: How to create an expense report from individual accounts

Tags: gnucash, expenses, annual-report

I'd like to calculate my average monthly spend over a year from an individual asset account to an individual expense account. Is there a way to do this please?

In the Expense Over Time report I can see how much I have spent from all asset accounts to one expense account but I can't seem to select one asset account. I have tried to use the contrl key to select the asset account and the expense account but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for any help.